# How to apply layoutConstraints for CustomTableView Cell

Tags: ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I need design custom cell like below with nslayoutconstraints by programtaically with visual format lanuguage as well as constraintswithitem.Any help will be appreciate one.

[image]

`    /* Intialize and assign Product Name */
        productName=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        productName.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0f];
        self.productName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.productName.numberOfLines = 0;
        productName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:productName];

```
    /* Intialize and assign Product Option */
    productOption=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    productOption.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    productOption.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0f];
    productOption.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255.0f green:128/255.0f blue:128/255.0f alpha:1.0f]; /* 808080 */
    [self.contentView addSubview:productOption];

    /* Intialize and assign Product Image */
    productImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    productImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    productImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    productImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5;
    productImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    productImageView.layer.borderColor =[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    productImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [self.contentView addSubview:productImageView];

    /* Intialize and assign List icon Image */
    listIconImage=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    listIconImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    listIconImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow.png"];
    [self.contentView addSubview:listIconImage];


   [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:7]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                multiplier:1
                                                                  constant:11.5]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:45]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:45]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productName
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:10]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productName
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:5]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productOption
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.productImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:10]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.productOption
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.productName
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:5]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listIconImage
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:-15.0f]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listIconImage
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:20.0f]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listIconImage
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:11.0f]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listIconImage
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0]];  `
```

The above is the code i have used to create this Design.Now i am struggling for how to get dynamic height in tableviewcontroller.It is always returning 0 when i am getting in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Thanks & Regards
Sam.P

Answer (score 0):

You should set tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension and also provide  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0f (estimated height, doesn't have to be exact);
More info in following link:
[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)